# cs50 speller keeps prompting free(): double free detected in tcache 2

Tags: c, cs50

I have been working on this problem set for quite a time and the code seems to be wrong but I couldn't find the solution. I have been comparing my code and other people's code but I still don't know where I got wrong. Really appreciate all your help if you can provide me with some ways to solve this problem. It keeps prompting me `free(): double free detected in tcache 2` but I can't seem to find my mistake.

```
// Implements a dictionary's functionality

#include <stdbool.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <strings.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include "dictionary.h"

// Represents a node in a hash table
typedef struct node
{
    char word[LENGTH + 1];
    struct node *next;
}
node;

// Number of buckets in hash table
const unsigned int N = 50;

// Hash table
node *table[N];

//word count
int count = 0;

// Returns true if word is in dictionary, else false
bool check(const char *word)
{
    // TODO
    bool found = false;
    node *current = table[hash(word)];
    while (current != NULL)
    {
        if (strcasecmp(current -> word, word) == 0)
        {
            found = true;
        }
        else if(current -> next != NULL)
        {
            current = current -> next;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return found;
}

// Hashes word to a number
unsigned int hash(const char *word)
{
    // TODO
    unsigned long hash = 5381;
    int c;
    while ((c = toupper(*word++)))
    {
        hash = ((hash << 5) + hash) + c; /* hash * 33 + c */
    }
    return hash % N;
}

// Loads dictionary into memory, returning true if successful, else false
bool load(const char *dictionary)
{
    // TODO
    FILE *infile = fopen(dictionary, "r");
    if (infile == NULL)
    {
        return false;
    }
    char buffer[LENGTH+1];
    while (fscanf(infile, "%s", buffer) != EOF)
    {   
        node *n = malloc(sizeof(node));
        strcpy(n -> word, buffer);
        n -> next = table[hash(buffer)];
        table[hash(buffer)] = n;
        count++;
        free(n);
    }
    fclose(infile);
    return true;
}

// Returns number of words in dictionary if loaded, else 0 if not yet loaded
unsigned int size(void)
{
    // TODO
    return count;
}

// Unloads dictionary from memory, returning true if successful, else false
bool unload(void)
{
    // TODO
    int num = count;
    for (int i = 0; i < N ; i++)
    {
        node *current = table[i];
        while (current != NULL)
        {   
            
            node *temp = current;
            current = current -> next;
            free(temp);
            num--;
        }
    }
    if (num == 0)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you need to call `free` in line 69?

Comment: because I allocated memory for node n and im supposed to free it?

Comment: Style guide: the dot `.` and arrow `->` operators bind very tightly
because they are [postfix operators](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.2.3).
They should not be written with spaces around them.
Writing `current -> word` is not idiomatic C and indicates that the coder
is a tyro (newbie).  Use `current->word`.

Comment: yes I'm new to C thanks for the reminder!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The calls of free in this while loop

```
while (fscanf(infile, "%s", buffer) != EOF)
{   
    node *n = malloc(sizeof(node));
    strcpy(n -> word, buffer);
    n -> next = table[hash(buffer)];
    table[hash(buffer)] = n;
    count++;
    free(n);
}
```

does not make a sense. You deleted at once (an object of the type `node` using the pointer `n`) what you was trying to add to the table (a valid address to an allocated object of the type `node`). As a result the element of the table at the position `hash(buffer)` that is set like

```
    table[hash(buffer)] = n;
```

has an invalid value because it is the address of the already deleted node in this statement

```
    free(n);
```

So in the function `unload` this invalid address will be again used to free already freed memory within the function `load`.

Pay attention to that you did not allocate memory as you wrote in a comment "for node `n`". `n` is just a pointer to the allocated unnamed object of the type node. So you are not freeing the pointer `n` itself in this statement

```
    free(n);
```

You are freeing the allocated object of the type node using the pointer `n`. Thus all pointers that pointed to the allocated object of the type `node` become invalid.